# spawn vs exec in nodejs - child_process

Tags: node.js, express

Lately I started learning node.js.I have a situation where I have to call multiple (say - 6 shell) scripts.Each script returns different json,at the end i have to create a new json by picking necessary fields from json's which each script returns using node and express.

eg: script json output:{"firstname":"xxx","lastname":"yyyy","account":"1234"}. 
I understand the difference between spawn and exec:
Referred this blog - http://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html

Since 'exec' has buffer limit,i am confused which is the perfect fit for my scenario.
Also i trying to figure out the way to execute script in parallel and return the output of 6 shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late but if you want to execute script in parallel check async module.

https://github.com/caolan/async

Check the parallel method.